Query regarding Dedekind cuts and multiplicative axioms
I am currently studying Dedekind cuts and I am going through the proof of the 5 multiplication field axioms. The first 4 are trivial (if x $\in$ F and y $\in$ F then xy $\in$ F, xy = yx, (xy)z = x(yz), 1x=x), but I am struggling on the 5th axiom which is concerned with finding a multiplicative inverse. I have thought of two constructions of an inverse, one being the set $\beta$ with all p $\in$ Q such that $\frac{1}{p} - r \notin \alpha$ for some r > 0 and the other being $\frac{1}{p}\frac{1}{r} \notin \alpha$ for some r > 1. I have found both constructions online. But I have a question regarding this construction.
Query regarding proof of Existence Theorem (1.19, pg-17, Baby Rudin)
In the final step, how can one prove that $w^n \in \alpha$ and that $w^{n+1} \notin \alpha$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$? This to me doesn't look obvious. I am going with this construction because I find that proving the fifth axiom is more difficult with the other construction.
Thanks in advance.

Do you know Bernoulli's inequality?  Specifically, you only need $(1+x)^m \geq 1+mx$ when $x>0$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$ (which is a simple corollary of the binomial theorem even if you didn't have access to Bernoulli)

Here is how I think this is going to work. In the original proof, $w>1$, so in the Bernoulli inequality we can set $x>1$. We get $x^{m+1} \geq m(x-1) + x > m(x-1) + 1$ and $x^m > 1+m(x-1)$. We can choose an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^{m+1}$ > $x^m$, and what follows is that we can have an $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $w^{n+1} \notin \alpha$ and $w^n \in \alpha$

In short, no, that doesn't work.   The inequality is used to show that integers $k < 0 < m$ exist such that $w^k \in \alpha$ and $w^m\notin\alpha$.  The existence of an $n$ such that $w^n \in\alpha$ and $w^{n+1}\notin\alpha$ follows easily from that.

I came up with a possible answer and I would like to know if I am right or not. In theorem 1.21 of Baby Rudin, it is stated that for every real number $x>0$ there exists an integer $n>0$, and only one positive and unique $y$ such that $y^n=x$. Here, since $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, using the theorem leads us to know that obviously there must be an integer $n$ such that $w^n \in \alpha$ and $w^{n+1} \notin \alpha$.

When proving $\mathbb{R}$ exists, we definitely cannot use a later theorem about the existence of roots in $\mathbb{R}$.

Sorry, I reviewed the proof for theorem 1.21 and I completely forgot that the existence theorem is used to prove that the supremum lies in $\mathbb{R}$
